# HTML link working improperly and showing up invisibly

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, formatting, styles

I am trying to add a simple HTML link to my code, however it is not showing up.  The links for the navigation bar show up just fine,however regular links are only showing up as invisible, meaning I can only see it by mousing over it and it does nothing.  I figure it could be a problem with the CSS styles I've created but I've gone over the code and cannot find anything wrong.

```
/*STYLE FORMATTING FOR THE NAVIGATION BAR*/
.nav ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#6b234b;
width:1000px;
}
.nav li
{
display: inline-block;
}
.nav a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:188.51px;
font-size:1.20em;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:"ostrich";
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#6b234b;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#a03771;
}

/*STYLE FORMATTING FOR REGULAR LINKS*/
.links a:link
{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:0.5em;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}
.links a:visited
{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:0.5em;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}

.links a:active
{
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:0.5em;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;}

.links a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:0.5em;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;}
```

This is the HTML link I am trying to implement with accompanying HTML.

```
<table style="float:left;">
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
<table style="padding-left:40px; max-width:530px;">

<!--BEGIN ENTRY-->
    <tr>
    <td>
        <p class="newsinfotitle">Info</p>       
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <img class="right" src="easterisland.jpg"/>
        <p class="newsinfo">Info</p>
        <a class="links" href="#">See More</a>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <hr/>
    </td>
    </tr>
<!--END ENTRY-->
```

Comment: Is that anchor nested into other tags?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. You will need to post more html. http://jsfiddle.net/8Dqtd/

Comment: Does this happen when you don't load the CSS at all?

Comment: In what browser does this fails?

Comment: It's failing in Firefox.  And yes, the anchor is nested in a table which is nested in another table. I'll post more HTML.  And I'll try and see if it loads without the CSS.

Comment: Works in IE, but incorrectly.  The link shows up regularly, but once I click it, it takes on the style of the .nav class.  I'm guessing this is a problem with the way my styles are implemented.  But I'm very new to CSS and don't have an eye yet for identifying these types of problems.

Comment: can you elaborate about your problem and what do you want in the result?

Comment: The problem is simply that the link <a class="links" href="#">See More</a> is invisible, and I don't know why as my code, as far as I can tell, is correct.  For the result, I just want that link to be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. and if you want to change bg color on active, just change there..

```
.nav a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:188.51px;
font-size:1.20em;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:"ostrich";
color:#666;enter code here
background-color:#6b234b;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.nav a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#6b234b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check this part in Your CSS

```
.nav a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:188.51px;
font-size:1.20em;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:"ostrich";
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#6b234b;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

You have given your link color `#FFFFFF` at visited.So when you are visiting the link it is changing the text of the link into white and as the background color is white,thats why the text are not visible. Just change the color there and you can get the good result.If any doubt comes let me know.

Comment: Well, that's the thing.  That only applies to the .nav class.  And the link I'm having trouble with is defined by the .links class, where the color of the link is consistently #000000

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.nav li {
display: inline-block;
}
.nav a:link,a:visited {
display:block;
width:188.51px;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:3px;
font-family:"ostrich";
color:#cccccc;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
}
.links a:link {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:12px;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}
a.links {
  color: #F00;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.links a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:12px;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}
.links a:active {
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:12px;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}
a.links:hover {
text-decoration:none;
font-size:12px;
text-align:right;
font-family:"hanzo";
color:#000000;
}
  </style>
```

Hope it will help you.You have one thing error.You have used `.links a:hover` which should be  `a.links:hover`.Hope this will help you.Just keep your css and markup clean after that you can do good.

Comment: Hmmm...it works, but that code messes up the style I set for my navigation bar.  I've figured out the problem,  but I don't know how to fix it.  The fact that I have two different link styles isn't being recognized clearly.  I changed the color of the links in the .nav class to #00000 and the links from the .links class inherit this style.  What's weird, however, is that it doesn't inherit ANY other attributes/formatting from either of the two classes.  And instead, any link outside of the navigation bar links appear as the default HTML links.

Comment: If you got the answer then just accept my answer by click on the right symbol icon and make it upvote and other thing your code has been messed up. So please make it clear.So the other user will clearly get your question.